# number of Tables in a HBase cluster

Tags: hbase

I am wondering what is the maximum number of tables in a HBase cluster, if it has 3 region servers. I know each table contains at least one region and one region server always contains 1000-1500 regions. So is that means the maximum number of tables = 1500 * 3 = 4500 ?

If each table is very small, is it possible that one region contains many tables so we can have millions of tables in HBase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing: do you really need thousand of tables? I don't think Hbase is a right tools in this case, you'll better use Redis map if your maps are small.

*So is that means the maximum number of tables = 1500 x 3 = 4500 ?*

-> There is no theorical limit on the number of tables in a Hbase cluster.

*If each table is very small, is it possible that one region contains many tables so we can have millions of tables in HBase?*

-> No: A region is a part of a table , is associated to it, and is loaded by only one regionserver.